# Не добавляются значения в базу данных

Tags: java, mysql

Хочу добавить меню в ресторан, но ничего не добавляется, кроме адреса и названия ресторана добавляю через постман вот так

```
{
    "restaurantName":"Mama Roma",
    "menu":[
        {"foodName":"Pizza",
        "foodDescription":"Good",
        "foodPrice":10},
        {"foodName":"Pizza",
        "foodDescription":"Good",
        "foodPrice":10},
        {"foodName":"Pizza",
        "foodDescription":"Good",
        "foodPrice":10}
    ],
    "address":{
        "country":"Latvia",
        "city":"Riga",
        "street":"Lacplesa"
    }

}
```

так же пыталась добавить через сервис меню, создавала метод

```
   public void addFoodItem(FoodMenu foodMenu){
        foodMenuRepository.save(foodMenu);
    }
```

но добавлялось все кроме айди ресторана, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне добавить меню в ресторан

[image: база данных]
Domain

Restaurant

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RESTAURANT_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String restaurantName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private List<FoodMenu> menu;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private Address address;

}
```

FoodMenu

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "FoodMenu")
public class FoodMenu {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "FOOD_MENU_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String foodName;

    private String foodDescription;

    private BigDecimal foodPrice;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESTAURANT_ID")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

}
```

Service

```
   @Service
    @Transactional
    public class RestaurantService {
        @Autowired
        private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;
    
        public void saveRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant){
             restaurantRepository.save(restaurant);
        }
    
        public List<Restaurant> allRestaurants(){
            return restaurantRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
 @RestController
    public class RestaurantController {
    
        @Autowired
        private RestaurantService restaurantService;
    
        @PostMapping("/create")
        public void createUploadRestaurant(@RequestBody Restaurant restaurant){
          restaurantService.saveRestaurant(restaurant);
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/showAllRestaurants")
        public List<Restaurant> showRestaurants(){
            return restaurantService.allRestaurants();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для добавления меню в классе `Restaurant` необходимо создать и использовать метод, в котором будет устанавливаться связь между экземплярами меню и ресторана (аналогично и для удаления).  Также лучше проинициализировать список заранее, чтобы не проверять затем на `null`:

```java
public class Restaurant {
// ... 

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private List<FoodMenu> menu = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private Address address;

    public void addMenu(FoodMenu menuItem) {
        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuItem.setRestaurant(this);
    }

    public void removeMenu(FoodMenu menuItem) {
        menu.remove(menuItem);
        menuItem.setRestaurant(null);
    }
}
```

Или же перед сохранением в базе экземпляра `Restaurant` принудительно установите связь между рестораном и его меню -- тогда при сохранении ресторана каскадно сохранятся и его пункты меню:

```java
public class RestaurantService {
    @Autowired
    private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;
    
    public void saveRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        // if (null != restaurant.getMenu()) { // проверка нужна для версии без инициализации
        for (FoodMenu item : restaurant.getMenu()) {
            item.setRestaurant(restaurant);
        }
        // }
        restaurantRepository.save(restaurant);
    }
//...    
}
```

---

Ещё один вариант -- обеспечить связь между `Restaurant` и `FoodMenu` во время десериализации, но для этого потребуется переопределить сеттер для соответствующего поля:

- "отключить" сеттер, сгенерированный ломбок-аннотацией
- написать свой сеттер (подобно коду, показанному выше для сервиса)

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RESTAURANT_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String restaurantName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "restaurant")
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private List<FoodMenu> menu;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private Address address;

    public void setMenu(List<FoodMenu> menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        if (this.menu != null) {
            this.menu.forEach(m -> m.setRestaurant(this));
        }
    }
}
```